# When I use a validation script in a form field, the value ends up being empty when I submit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, forms, elementor, form-fields

I started studying Javascript about two weeks ago and I'm already trying to do some stuff for my company's website.

We have a wordpress elementor website, in which I created a new registration form, using javascript and Jquery to validate some specific fields, like CPF(like a SS number for brazilians), zip code and password.

All of these validation scripts are working fine, but just one of them (CPF), when I submit the form it sends without any value in this specific field.

Hope you guys can help me.

I used the following script to validate data of this field:

````
        <input type="text" class="elementor-field elementor-size-lg  elementor-field-textual" name="form-fields[field_cpf]" id="field_cpf" placeholder="Digite apenas números."  maxlength="11" minlength="11" onblur="alertarFuncao()" required="required" aria-required="true">

<script>
//validation script
function verificaCPF(strCpf) {     
    var soma;
    var resto;
    soma = 0;
    if (strCpf == "00000000000" ||
        strCpf == "11111111111" ||
        strCpf == "22222222222" ||
        strCpf == "33333333333" ||
        strCpf == "44444444444" ||
        strCpf == "55555555555" ||
        strCpf == "66666666666" ||
        strCpf == "77777777777" ||
        strCpf == "88888888888" ||
        strCpf == "99999999999") {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        soma = soma + parseInt(strCpf.substring(i - 1, i)) * (11 - i);
    }
    
    resto = soma % 11;
    
    if (resto == 10 || resto == 11 || resto < 2) {
        resto = 0;
    } else {
        resto = 11 - resto;
    }
    
    if (resto != parseInt(strCpf.substring(9, 10))) {
        return false;
    }
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        soma = soma + parseInt(strCpf.substring(i - 1, i)) * (12 - i);
    }
    resto = soma % 11;
    
    if (resto == 10 || resto == 11 || resto < 2) {
        resto = 0;
    } else {
        resto = 11 - resto;
    }
    
    if (resto != parseInt(strCpf.substring(10, 11))) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;

    }
//function if the field validation script returns false
    function campoInvalido(fieldId) {
        fieldId.style.borderColor = "red"

    }
//function if the field validation script returns true
    function campoValido(fieldId) {
        fieldId.style.borderColor = "green"
        
    }

//function that runs when the user clicks/taps out off the field
    function alertarFuncao() {
        var strCpf = document.getElementById('field_cpf').value; 
        verificaCPF(strCpf);
        if (!verificaCPF(strCpf)) {
            campoInvalido(document.getElementById('field_cpf'))
            alert('Por favor, insira um CPF válido.');            
        } else {
            campoValido(document.getElementById('field_cpf'));
            return document.getElementById('field_cpf').value = strCpf
        }
    }

</script>```
````

Comment: The only line of code I see that would modify the form field is `return document.getElementById('field_cpf').value = strCpf`, what happens if you remove that line?

Comment: There are some really very odd things with the js code - but that said - are you sure the html element name `form-fields[field_cpf]` is correct? Possibly just `name="field_cpf"`

Comment: @James It happens the same. Actually I inserted that line as an attempt to make it work, but the e-mail still arrive with the field with blank value.

Comment: @Fraser I bet there is haha, I'm a total newbie in programming. But about the field name I just used the same pattern as the other fields of elementor, I don't think there's anything to do with that. But thanks (:

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code snipet on my own web server, and once I found an input which passes your checks it seems to work.

I see however that you didn't include a  element in your snippet. The input must be a child of one of these elements in order to send data. If you have a closing tag  directly above this input field you should probably move it under.

Comment: Hey Sander, first of all thank you very much for your effort!
But what you said about the tags really makes sense. As I've said, I'm using the elementor form, this field is an HTML custom field that I created in order to make with more customizable settings. 

So, correct me if I'm wrong but I cannot change the order of HTML tags in WordPress right?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem turning the HTML custom field of elementor form into a regular text field, and did some modifications on the script, inserting an event listener to it. As I understood this is an Elementor form "problem", it doesn't recognize values in custom HTML fieds when submitting.

Here's the modified code:

````
    var soma;
    var resto;
    soma = 0;
    if (strCpf == "00000000000" ||
        strCpf == "11111111111" ||
        strCpf == "22222222222" ||
        strCpf == "33333333333" ||
        strCpf == "44444444444" ||
        strCpf == "55555555555" ||
        strCpf == "66666666666" ||
        strCpf == "77777777777" ||
        strCpf == "88888888888" ||
        strCpf == "99999999999") {
        return false;
    }
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) {
        soma = soma + parseInt(strCpf.substring(i - 1, i)) * (11 - i);
    }
    
    resto = soma % 11;
    
    if (resto == 10 || resto == 11 || resto < 2) {
        resto = 0;
    } else {
        resto = 11 - resto;
    }
    
    if (resto != parseInt(strCpf.substring(9, 10))) {
        return false;
    }
    
    soma = 0;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        soma = soma + parseInt(strCpf.substring(i - 1, i)) * (12 - i);
    }
    resto = soma % 11;
    
    if (resto == 10 || resto == 11 || resto < 2) {
        resto = 0;
    } else {
        resto = 11 - resto;
    }
    
    if (resto != parseInt(strCpf.substring(10, 11))) {
        return false;
    }
    
    return true;

    }

    function campoInvalido(fieldId) {
        fieldId.style.borderColor = "red"

    }

    function campoValido(fieldId) {
        fieldId.style.borderColor = "green"
        
    }

    function alertarFuncao() {
        var strCpf = document.getElementById('form-field-field_cpf').value; 
        verificaCPF(strCpf);
        if (!verificaCPF(strCpf)) {
            campoInvalido(document.getElementById('form-field-field_cpf'))
            alert('Por favor, insira um CPF válido.');            
        } else {
            campoValido(document.getElementById('form-field-field_cpf'));
            return document.getElementById('form-field-field_cpf').value = strCpf
        }
    }
    
    document.getElementById('form-field-field_cpf').addEventListener("blur", alertarFuncao);```
````